# How to both scroll and center inside a flex div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to have a panel (a div) center inside a container (a div with flex display).

When the panel is small in height (just change "height: 300px" in my example CSS), it works OK. When the panel is higher ("height: 3000px") than its container, I want to be able to scroll page the **whole** page (Note I have "overflow-y: auto" on the body).

The issue is the container does not wrap completely the inner div. If you scroll down you can see the red stops and green overflows:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
      overflow-y: auto;
}

.h100 {
    height: 100%;
}

.flex-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-item-stretch {
    flex: 1 1;
}

.panel {
    height: 3000px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: green;

}

.justify-content-center {
    justify-content: center;
}


.vscroll {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.m-auto {
    margin: auto;
}

.container {
    background-color: red;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="flex-col h100">
        <div>
            <span>LOGO</span>
        </div>
        <div class="container flex-col flex-item-stretch m-auto">
            <div>Title</div>
            <div class="panel flex-item-stretch m-auto"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you need to add `flex-shrink: 0;` to the element `panel`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Uhh, thanks but I have another issue now.... You already set my question as a duplicate, could you please remove it so I can edit the question?

Comment: first edit your question then I will remove the duplicate if it's not a suitable one

Comment: by the wat I am pretty sure you issue is related to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278725/centered-flex-container-grows-beyond-top/49279237#49279237

Comment: @TemaniAfif OK, I edited the question. Please remove the "duplicate" mark as it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: check the second duplicate I added and you will get your answer

Comment: @TemaniAfif wow amazing, Thank you. Setting margin: auto worked. I need to try to understand why it's working like that.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks again, you rock.

Comment: If you add a comment, I will mark it as answer.

Comment: since it's a duplicate no need to add an answer as there is already one in the duplicate. and if you want a deep understanding you can check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455342/8620333

Comment: For anyone else who reads this. As far as I can tell you need margin-auto on any other nested flexboxes to make it work.

Comment: I spoke too soon. The behavior is not consistent across Chrome and Firefox. Moreover it doesn't actually work on neither on them, the container is oveflown. Please see my code.

Comment: you didn't define any `overflow: auto;` so it's logical to have overflow

Comment: I did, look at the body in CSS, it has "overflow-y: auto;"

Comment: the body doesn't need to have overflow, you need to apply overflow to the flex container if you don't want your container to overflow ... `.container{overflow: auto;}`

Comment: Please look to my description. I want the whole page to be scrollable.

Comment: then remove `.h100`.. not sure what you are looking for, you are applying some style then you are surprised why they are like that ... you explicitely said that the red div should be height:100% so it logical that you have overflow, don't specify any height and it will be ok

Comment: if I remove .h100 and the panel has a small height, how is it going to get vertically centered?

Comment: that's why I don't know what you really want ... *you* are using style that you don't want as there is no issue everything is working fine. Probably you need `min-height:100%` ?

Comment: If you don't know what I want why did you mark my question as duplicate? Doesn't make any sense

Comment: I though I explained clearly what I want. I need a way to be able to scroll whole page when panel is tall and have the panel centered when its height is smaller than its container

Comment: read your own comments and you will understand why I marked as duplicate. you clearly said by yourself that everything was ok so ask yourself.

Comment: So basically you're not going to actually help me, you're just satisfied with marking question as duplicates however you think it suits you. Great job.

Comment: I think I am the *only* one helping you here. I replied to all your comments and each time I provide you with a solution but well we are always faulty here. Did you try `min-height:100%` .. I think not, you are complaining about me helping you