# Scroll not working with Flex align-self and viewheight

Tags: html, css

I try to create a template for something like a chat.
I want to display the text at the bottom of the div, why i use `flex` and `flex-end` for the child parent. But then as soon i do this my scroll function breaks.

https://jsfiddle.net/e1n7pc42/1/

i heard my jsfiddle is not working, so here my code:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="output">
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
  </div>   
</div>


<div class="main"></div>
```

```
.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 70vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
}

.output {
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.main {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 20vh;
}
```

Comment: related to understand why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49279237/8620333

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: delete align-self: flex-end;

Comment: Im sorry my fiddle isnt working, so i included the code in the OP.

Comment: Deleting align-self: flex-end; does make my text start from the top not from the bottom which i want..

Comment: Why do i get downvotes, i tried a lot and made a jsfiddle and even pastet my code now in here whats wrong here? I would be happy if people would tell me what im doing wrong so i can prevent it next time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding **margin-top: auto;** will help here.

```css
.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 70vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;

}

.output {
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin-top: auto;

}

.main {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 20vh;
}§
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="output">
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
      <span> <p>Hello World! </p> </span>
  </div>   
</div>


<div class="main"></div>
```