# How to provide correct height and vertical scrolling of non-shinking flex child in column flex layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In below column flex layout, the top and bottom paddings has been defined for `.Layout-MainContent` (orange part):

[image]

```html
<div class="Layout">
  <div class="Layout-Header">
    <div class="Layout-Header-DummyLogo"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="Layout-MainContent">
    <div class="SignInForm">
      <div class="SignInForm-DummyHeading"></div>
      <div class="SignInForm-DummyInputField"></div>
      <div class="SignInForm-DummyInputField"></div>
      <div class="SignInForm-DummyInputField"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FFF9C4;
}


.Layout-Header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 12px 8px;
  background: #5C6BC0;
}

.Layout-Header-DummyLogo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #303F9F;
}

.Layout-MainContent {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 24px 0 36px;
  background: #FFCC80;
}

.SignInForm {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 32px 40px 20px;
  background: #42A5F5;
}

.SignInForm-DummyHeading {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #1976D2;
}

.SignInForm-DummyInputField {
  margin-top: 24px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #1976D2;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ufg36r7/4/)

The first strange thing is bottom padding is not `36px` as defined (**update**: looks like  it's because of the JSFiddle console):

[image]

But this question topic is incorrect behavior on low viewports. I am expecting the vertical scrolling in `.Layout-MainContent`, but it's height must not become lower than natural (sum of paddings and children height). The real behavior is top and bottom paddings `.Layout-MainContent` are being completely ignored and also a part of `.SignInForm` has been truncated:

[image]

I know that `flex: 1 1 auto;` is contradicts to **non-shinking** requirement, but if we change to `flex: 1 0 auto;` the scrolling will completely disappear. How to keep both scrolling and minimal natural height if `.Layout-MainContent`

Comment: remove the centrin from the parent and use margin:auto on child: https://jsfiddle.net/ctesm6n2/

Comment: @TemaniAfif, thank you for the solution. To exhaust this question, would you please to explain why above phenomenon happen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49279237/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif, got it! I can't thank you enough!